# How to use jQuery to change the default ASP.NET / ASP.NET Core validation message?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, validation

Have a simple form which uses the .net built in validation like:

```
<input asp-for="ClientName" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="ClientName" class="text-danger"></span>
```

And the generated html is like:

```
<input class="form-control input-validation-error" type="date" 
       data-val="true" data-val-required="The Client Name field is required." 
       id="ClientName" name="ClientName" value="" 
       aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ClientName-error">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" 
          data-valmsg-for="ClientName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
        <span id="ClientName-error" class="">The Client Name field is required.</span>
    </span>
```

I am trying to replace the default validation message "The Client Name field is required." to something different on the fly using jQuery after press the submit form button. Would this be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am trying " anything is possible, perhaps show what you tried so we can assist you in fixing it...

Comment: I am not sure why you want to achieve this feature, Do you want to show different error messages according to different situations in the view?

Comment: @XinranShen, it's a quick hack to replace the validation text using a different language depending on machine language. For all the static elements, it's easy, but .net validation message element is generated on the fly I believe, to replace that after press the button is something I can't figure out.

Comment: So you just wanna achieve Globalization and Localization of Model Validation Messages in asp.net core?

Comment: @XinranShen Yes, but without making a lot changes in the backend, that's why I chose to use this hack to embed the pre-defined validation message in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your submit button is a input type submit. You can simply do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //caputre click event on this button (change :submit if the button is anything else)
    $(':submit').click(function () {
        //change the text inside of the message box
        $('.text-danger').text('Your custom validation message.');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the button is a simple submit <input id="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />. Instead of using the css class $('.text-danger').text, could I use the id of the span tag generated ('#ClientName-error').text? Cause it seems the value was set before the page was refreshed/loaded again then the default message is used, not the new one.

Comment: of course you can. you can also use .innerHTML instead of text if you whant to add h1 or paragraphs for example.

Comment: It still doesn't work, seems the default validation message overwrites the new one.

Comment: That means you didn't stop the form to be sent. block it with `event.preventDefault()` (the event to catch is `yourForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {  });`. So inside of it, you use the preventDefault() and you do your checking and only if everything ok you do the submit